# Java - stuck in infinite loop when calling classes

Tags: java, swing, infinite-loop, maze

When attempting to run the program, I am caught in an infinite loop and cannot break out. - I have tried making the different class calls private , however, it did not change anything.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


 class Mazes extends JPanel {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new Mazes();
     }

     public Mazes() throws FileNotFoundException {

         JFrame f = new JFrame("Maze");
         f.add(new Board());
         f.setSize(500, 500);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.pack();
         f.setVisible(true);
     }
 }
```

Board class

```
   class Board extends JPanel {
     Boolean[][] maze = getMaze();
     int row = maze.length;
     private Ball b = new Ball();


    public Boolean[][] getMaze() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Boolean[][] maze = Exercise4.readMaze();
        return maze;
     }

    public Board() throws FileNotFoundException {
        add(b);
    }  

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < row; x++) {

                 if (maze[y][x].equals(false)) {
                     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                     g.fillRect(x * 25, y * 25, 120, 120);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    g.fillRect(x * 25, y * 25, 120, 120);
                }
             }
         }
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.fillOval((row - 1) * 24 - 5, (row - 1) * 24 - 5, 20, 20);

     }


     @Override
     public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         return new Dimension(row * 25, row* 25);
    }
}
```

Ball class

```
class Ball extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

     int x = 25, y = 25, vx = 25, vy = 25, tileX = 0, tileY = 0;
     private Board test = new Board(); // I believe the problem lies here when constructing the new Board, as it recalls the ball in the Board class again.
     Boolean[][] maze = test.getMaze();

        @Override
         protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
             super.paintComponent(graphics);
             Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
             setBounds(0,0, 25*600,25*600);
             setOpaque(false);
             g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
             g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(20, 20);
        }

        public Ball() throws FileNotFoundException {
        addKeyListener(new AL());
             setFocusable(true);

        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }

        public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
            @Override 
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int code = e.getKeyCode();
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    if (!maze[tileX][tileY].equals(false)) {
                        y -= vy;
                        tileY += 1;
                        repaint();
                }
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {    }
        }
    }
```

Basically, I the calling goes:
Main class --> Board class --> Ball class (adds player to maze) --> Board class

I am stuck in a constructor loop, and do not know how to fix/change it.

Im trying to just call the board constructor from the Board class in the Ball class: I have commented where I believe the problem occurs.

I have done this in attempt to reference the maze(Board) in the Ball class to make collisions viable --> the Ball class without with Board constructor or collision conditions runs fine as a ball on a board.

Comment: You have mutual recursion between Ball and Board. Think about it though, does it really make any sense for a ball to contain a board?

Comment: Why don't you pass the board as a parameter to the ball constructor (or vice versa). What you currently have is an infinite loop of constructor calls.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no it doesn't, however, I could not find another way to reference the Board in the Ball class without it throwing a non-static error.

Comment: @Aresouman It's too early in the morning for me to reason what you're doing here, but your design doesn't make any sense. First, get rid of the board inside ball since that doesn't make any intuitive sense and even if it does get rid of an error, it's a separate board, so it likely doesn't do any you intend anyway.

Comment: You also never even use the board inside ball, so theres no point in creating it. Even if you were using board in ball, I'd argue that suggests you do a redesign. There's probably very few cases were a ball needs knowledge of the board. It means you have the ball dealing with things it should be dealing with.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, sorry about that, lemme just rephrase a little (minus the Board constructor in the Ball class). Im trying to reference the maze from Board in Ball. thats pretty much what im trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Aresouman Why does the ball need knowledge of the maze?

Comment: @Carcigenicate to detect where the wall is:    if (!maze[tileX]tileY].equals(false))->move,  its a Boolean array so false = wall.

Comment: @Aresouman You probably shouldn't be handling collisions from within the ball. Whatever class moves the ball would be a more appropriate place to deal with that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate cheers for the help, ill try get that done